# Why mysql import tablespace so slow with insert/update sql pressure？

Tags: mysql

I have schema A and B in my mysql,when I do a pressure test on schema A which include  lots of concurrent batch insert and update sql operation and import many tablespace from files which was exported by xtrabackup on schema B.I found the import operation is very slow and cost lots of time (more than one hour). If I don't do pressure test on schema A and the import operation just cost 20 seconds nearly.

`show processlist:
856 guest   10.142.90.17:51671  pinc_0002   Query   733 Table lock  alter table bill import tablespace  0
857 guest   10.142.90.17:51700  pinc_0002   Query   733 Table lock  alter table company import tablespace   0
858 guest   10.142.90.17:51731  pinc_0002   Query   733 Table lock  alter table car_new import tablespace   0
859 guest   10.142.90.17:51758  pinc_0002   Query   733 Table lock  alter table dialing_his import tablespace   0
860 guest   10.142.90.17:51799  pinc_0002   Query   733 Table lock  alter table car import tablespace   0
861 guest   10.142.90.17:51846  pinc_0002   Query   732 Table lock  alter table employee_his_new import tablespace  0
862 guest   10.142.90.17:51869  pinc_0002   Query   732 Table lock  alter table book import tablespace  0
863 guest   10.142.90.17:51914  pinc_0002   Query   732 Table lock  alter table goods import tablespace 0
864 guest   10.142.90.17:51975  pinc_0002   Query   732 Table lock  alter table order_details import tablespace 0`

[result of SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BySuFoFiVt1ORnF5UElUT3p4OGc)

`` select * from information_schema.INNODB_LOCKS:
115155367:9417:4:2  115155367   X   RECORD  `pinc_0003`.`testcolumn`    GEN_CLUST_INDEX 9417    4   2   0x00001D331DDF
115153055:9417:4:2  115153055   X   RECORD  `pinc_0003`.`testcolumn`    GEN_CLUST_INDEX 9417    4   2   0x00001D331DDF
115150974:9417:4:2  115150974   X   RECORD  `pinc_0003`.`testcolumn`    GEN_CLUST_INDEX 9417    4   2   0x00001D331DDF
115148337:9417:4:2  115148337   X   RECORD  `pinc_0003`.`testcolumn`    GEN_CLUST_INDEX 9417    4   2   0x00001D331DDF ``

[result of select * from  information_schema.INNODB_TRX](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ew6FH.png)

`top:
PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND

54996 apps      20   0  111g  71g 8664 S 1794.7 14.2   2254:20 mysqld`

iostat -dxm：
```
[apps@cs1n3 ~]$ iostat -dxm 2
Linux 2.6.32-358.el6.x86_64 (cs1n3)     02/08/2017  _x86_64_    (64 CPU)

Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rMB/s    wMB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await  svctm  %util
sda               0.04   485.19    8.12   76.89     0.19     2.43    63.20     0.19    2.25   0.16   1.38
sdb               0.00     8.14    0.03    2.44     0.00     0.04    35.10     0.01    4.51   0.14   0.04

Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rMB/s    wMB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await  svctm  %util
sda               0.00   841.50    0.00 7003.50     0.00    63.91    18.69     3.13    0.45   0.13  94.20
sdb               0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
```

```
iostat -dxm
Linux 2.6.32-358.el6.x86_64 (cs1n3)     02/08/2017  _x86_64_    (64 CPU)
Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rMB/s    wMB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await  svctm  %util
sda               0.04   485.19    8.12   76.89     0.19     2.43    63.20     0.19    2.25   0.16   1.38
sdb               0.00     8.14    0.03    2.44     0.00     0.04    35.10     0.01    4.51   0.14   0.04

Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rMB/s    wMB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await  svctm  %util
sda               0.00   841.50    0.00 7003.50     0.00    63.91    18.69     3.13    0.45   0.13  94.20
sdb               0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe answer is in your table architecture. If you have `PRIMARY_KEY` in yours tables, your database has `B-Tree` structure, but if you have tables without `PRIMARY_KEY`, your database has `table` structure. So, maybe you have `table` structure in your database, so operation add/update costs more than `B-Tree` structure.

Comment: I've 1 table with non-PRIMARY_KEY,and 19 table with PRIMARY_KEY,And I found restart mysql server,and then import tablespace only cost nearly 20 mins.

Comment: which it is less or more, whether the same?

Comment: Maybe good idea is add to all table PRIMARY_KEY? Please check this